How to satisfy the invitation letter requirement for Spain when the final destination is not Spain
I want to invite a friend from Central America to stay by me and visit Italy as a tourist. My friend is a non-EU national and does not need a visa to enter the Schengen Area.
Since Madrid is a major transit hub for flights from Central America, my friend's flight will likely land there first. Spain requires an invitation letter (carta de invitación) for this purpose.
However, I am an Italian citizen and not a Spanish resident, so I cannot provide a Spanish invitation letter. Additionally, even if I could provide one, the letter would need to specify the address where my friend will stay in Spain, which is not applicable since they will only be in Spain for a layover at the airport.
I was expecting this to be a very common issue with solutions, but I couldn't find any.
Is there a solution?
Notes:

My friend will be staying by me, not in a hotel or tourist accommodation, which makes the invitation letter a requirement (it seems that the letter is not required if staying at a hotel or other tourist accommodation)
The invitation letter is a requirement for any non-EU national, regardless of whether they need a visa; if they need a visa, the invitation letter must be submitted to the appropriate embassy when asking for a visa; otherwise, it must be presented at immigration when entering the border.
Although not especially relevant, as the above would apply to any non-EU national which however doesn't require a visa for visiting as a tourist, my friend is from Honduras.
My friend wouldn't be leaving the airport, but that doesn't change the requirement (speaking from experience, as I've had another friend from Honduras who was traveling with me almost sent back to Honduras while trying to pass Spanish immigration; luckily, because I was there in person and I was somehow able to convince the immigration officer that they would proceed with their onward trip to Italy together with me, they let my friend pass, as an exception).


By 'layover' do you mean that your friend will enter Spain, or will be in airside transit? Isn't the invitation letter only needed when you are staying with a person, rather than having a hotel booking for the layover and proof of final destination?

Can you clarify your friend’s citizenship and why a letter of invitation would be required for someone who doesn’t need a visa?

@jcaron AFAIK the invitation requirement is required by all visitors regardless of visa. The One Stop Problem Shop says "This has nothing to do with any Visa obligation. For Nationals from Non EU countries with or without a required Visa to enter Spain, the Carta de Invitación is an accommodation requirement and if you cannot show a booking for tourist accommodation, then is required instead."

To the OP's deleted comment: But where are they staying in their Madrid layover? Do they go landside? My link says they don't need a letter if they are staying in booked acccomodation. Only if they can't show a tourist booking. Your friend is not staying with you, in Spain, but is in transit. There must be millions of people who transit through the hub in such circumstances.

@WeatherVane as clarified twice in the question, my friend is staying by me. There is no booked accommodation. I have also moved my other replies to the Notes section of my question, for clarity. Hence the deleted comment.

But you aren't in Spain. You are in Italy. Please clarify exactly what your friend will do in Madrid. a) transit airside, b) transit landside, c) layover in some unbooked hotel.

Is the onward flight with the same airline on the same ticket? Why do they need to pass Spanish immigration at a major hub?

@WeatherVane while that mostly depends on the flight arrangement which can only be known when flights will be booked, the requirement seems to apply either way, as I've experienced at the border in the past, when flying with another friend from Honduras. After all, both Spain and Italy are Schengen and Spain would be the port of entry into the Schengen area, even if in transit. Added clarification to the question.

So book a through flight with the same airline on the same ticket, and transit airside. Then they don't enter Spain.

@WeatherVane they enter Schengen in Spain, which is their port of entry to the Schengen area. Immigration would be in Spain either way.

If they are in airside transit, they don't go through immigration. They don't enter Spain, otherwise Madrid would be useless as an international hub. If they pass though immigration, they need either a tourist booking, or a letter of invitation.

@WeatherVane in this specific situation I would love that to be true, but unfortunately that's not how Schengen works.

Then get a hotel booking.

Why don’t you just route your friend’s transit through a non Schengen airport, and onwards to Italy? Or via another Schengen country thst doesn’t have the invitation requirement?

@WeatherVane you must have missed OP’s friend final destination. OP’s friend is going Honduras-Spain-Italy, so they will be entering Schengen in Spain and will necessarily go through Spanish border control, even if they have airside transit. But this all seems like a terrible deviation from Schengen regulations. A ticket to Italy, a handwritten letter of invitation from OP,  a ticket back to Honduras (or proof of funds showing the ability to buy one), and proof of funds showing the ability to sustain themselves for the duration of the trip should be enough.

@jcaron I didn't miss that they are going to Italy. Otherwise I wouldn't have posted any of the above comments.

@WeatherVane why are you saying they won’t enter Spain then? Of course they will, as long as they go through Spanish immigration (will they will) they are in Spain (even if only for a few hours).

Spain being in Schengen, the Schengen Borders Code applies.
It tells us in 6.1.c that one of the conditions of entry for non-EU nationals is:

they justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay, and they have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit to a third country into which they are certain to be admitted, or are in a position to acquire such means lawfully;

And in 6.3:

A non-exhaustive list of supporting documents which the border guard may request from the third-country national in order to verify the fulfilment of the conditions set out in paragraph 1 (c) is included in Annex I.

And in Annex I:

(c) for journeys undertaken for the purposes of tourism or for private reasons:
(i) supporting documents as regards lodging:

an invitation from the host if staying with one;
a supporting document from the establishment providing lodging or any other appropriate document indicating the accommodation envisaged;

(ii) supporting documents as regards the itinerary:

confirmation of the booking of an organised trip or any other appropriate document indicating the envisaged travel plans;

(iii) supporting documents as regards return:

a return or round-trip ticket;


So they need to show:

the ticket or boarding pass for their flight to Italy

An invitation letter from you. If you were in Spain it would be a Carta de Invitacion. Since you are in Italy, use the Italian model, like for a visa. See for instance https://consboston.esteri.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/hostinvitationletter.pdf
A simple handwritten letter with similar details is probably enough since they are an Annex II national, but you may want to err on the side of caution, especially if you are sponsoring the whole trip and not just providing lodging.

Ideally, a ticket back out of Schengen, or proof of funds showing they can buy one

Proof of funds showing they have means of subsistence for the duration of the trip in Italy (there’s a fixed daily amount per day I’m too lazy to look up now).


A Spanish Carta de Invitación would be required if they stayed in Spain, which is not the case. But you have to prove that (ticket or boarding pass to Italy) and show the letter of invitation for Italy instead.
Note that, like in a visa application, they also need to convince the border agent that they are a bona fide visitor, with a legitimate reason (in your case that you are really friends and that there is a good reason for you to invite them), going back home (or anywhere outside Schengen, really) in time, will not work, etc.
That is possibly what was the issue last time you entered with another Honduran citizen, rather than having or not having a Carta de Invitacion (other possibilities could be that they did not show the itinerary to Italy or they they didn’t have a letter of invitation from you).

Thank you for your elaborate answer. Last time we entered, the officer mentioned that the carta de invitación was a requirement regardless of the tickets for onward travel that we had. This is the tricky part. Despite having me there as a human-sized, EU, breathing and living invitation letter, if you will. But I won't be there next time. I agree that the documents you listed should be enough, in principle, for a reasonable and successful assessment by the immigration officers. As always with immigration, no guarantees.

@magma Since you are not eligible to apply for a spanish invitation, an italian one should be suffient. Carta de invitación - Spain Service Immigration (non-official source): Who can request the letter of invitation to Spain?: 'It must be requested by the host. That is, by the Spaniard or foreigner with legal residence in Spain who is going to welcome the foreigner into his home.'
